# WindowState of all derived forms are changing together

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop, inheritance

On my windows application written with C#, I have written a form named BaseForm. On this form I have a Maximise button, white the following code:

```
private void btnMaximise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal ?
    FormWindowState.Maximized : FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Now I have several forms derived from BaseForm. When I click the Maximise button on Say Form1, all other derived forms are maximized together, and when I click the button again, they all go back to their normal WindowState, TOGETHER.

I do not understand why this happens. I thought when I say **this.WindowState** I am pointing to the **initiated object**, but it is acting like a **Static** one. When I click the button on Form1 I expect only Form1 to get maximized and not all forms with common inheritance.

In the Designer.cs file, the event handler is linked like below:

```
this.btnMaximise.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnMaximise_Click);
```

By the way, all these forms are MDI children to an MDI Parent form. Maybe that has something to do with the problem.

New test result:
I tried opening 2 forms with MDI Parent set, and 2 other without it. The result is strange. Those which are independant (without MDI Parent) have no conflict, and those with MDI Parent all behave the same. Even when a form with MDI Parent is maximized and I open an entirely new form (not with CTRL+TAB, with instantiating a new form, setting the MDI Parent, and calling its .Show() method) the new form is opened with Maximized state.

Comment: Show us how you linked this event handler up. I'm also curious why you seem to have reimplemented a button that every form has already, using functionality that seems to be the same as default maximise behavior

Comment: @CaiusJard
this.btnMaximise.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnMaximise_Click);

Comment: Can you show the surrounding context too? EDit your question please, rather than posts  code in comments (bad formatting, and soon I will re move my comments when the info is added)

Comment: @CaiusJard additional information added to the question, please check again and note that the forms are opened as mdi children

Comment: Won't happen if `Form1`, `Form2`, .. are ***new*** instances of `BaseForm`.

Comment: ahh MDI children. No, not all of them are maximized or restored, just one. When you maximize a MDI child it fills the entire client area and you won't see the other MDI children, and when you restore it, the last location and size are restored. So, you just imagining that all of them are maximized and restored together.

Comment: To test that yourself, maximize a child and `foreach (var f in Application.OpenForms.OfType<BaseForm>()) Console.WriteLine(f.WindowState);`. The output will tell you something.

Comment: @JQSOFT when I maximize Form1, it fills the area. When I press CTRL+TAB Form2 comes to focus in maximized state.

Comment: Exactly. This is how it works. When you do that `Form1` and `Form2` _exchange_ the window state. As if you restored `Form1` then maximized `Form2`.

Comment: Take the code I posted, paste it over the top of Form1 in a new project called WindowsFormsApp1 and run it. Press the max button to maximize one of the children, then press the regular minimize (nothing in my code can be responsible for a minimize) and see that none of the other children behind the was-maximized-now-minimized form are maximized. Now check if your app behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue; you'll need to post more code as to how you're creating, subclassing and wiring these events up. Here is a complete example code that DOESN'T demonstrate the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.IsMdiContainer = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                new DerivedForm(this).Show();
        }
    }

    public class DerivedForm : BaseForm {
        public DerivedForm(Form parent)
        {
            this.MdiParent = parent;
        }
    }

    public class BaseForm : Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = "Max";
            b.Click += B_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(b);
        }

        private void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal ? FormWindowState.Maximized : FormWindowState.Normal;        
        }
    }
}
```

Post something like this that does reproduce your issue and we will tell you why, or examine how this works and make your setup the same